# Passing an array of objects as a function parameter gives me an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, filter

why do i get an `Object` when I pass an `Array` of `Objects` as function parameter?

`How i call the Function:`

```
searchMicroservices(this.microservices, this.search)
```

`Array:`

```
search: '',
microservices: [ 
{title: 'test', description:'test' },
{title: 'test1', description: 'test1},
....
]
```

`Function:`

```
searchMicroservices: function (array, searchValue) {
      //this console log logs an object.
      console.log(array)
      return array.filter((microservice) => {
        return microservice.title.toUpperCase().match(searchValue.toUpperCase())
      })
    }
```

This is the console log output in the browser:

[image: Console log of the function]

This is the error I get because I'm using `filter` method on the `object` which should be the `array`.

[image: Error of filter method on object]

It's probably something simple but I somehow can't figure it out.

Comment: Use Vue devtools to be sure that it's the type you're expecting. Also, how do you pass it?

Comment: How do you call the `searchMicroservices` function?

Comment: Might be nice to see the full file.
Or if you can just share the `<script></script>` section that would be perfect.

You might be adding your instance properties wrongly.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim `this.searchMicroservices(this.microservices, this.search)` this is how i call the function and pass the array.

Comment: This is not enough. Please provide a full scope with all the required context so that we could replicate it on our side. We basically need a [repro].

Comment: If the microservices-array is part of the vue data-object and searchMicroservices a method in the same vue-object, then there is no nead to pass the array as parameter, just use this.microservices inside the method.

Comment: Yes I will edit my question with more code asap.

Comment: @OnkiHara Yes I know but i want to use the this search on different arrays and my teachers wont be happy if there is to many duplicate code.

Comment: 20 lines of code is better than 3 of text.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't name your first parameter 'array'. Probably there is confusion with the JS Array-Object.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that object value was provided where an array was expected, this includes primitive values that are coerced to built-in constructor instances.

There's no way how provided code can cause this, considering that `microservices` is array prop.

Console output shows that `microservices` is component instance. There's likely a ref of the same name that isn't shown in the question. In this case prop and ref names shouldn't be in conflict.